# How to properly rsync / folder?

Tags: rsync

I want `rsync` the `/` folder with a btrfs snapshot. How to avoid a potential crash? Should I exclude some folders such as `/proc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple `rsync` command to backup your full filesystem, consider using these options:

```
# -a --archive
# -v --verbose
# -A --acls
# -X --xattrs
# -x --one-file-system
# --numeric-ids
```

The `-aAX` options preserve permissions, mode, owner, group, mtime, ACLs and xattrs. The `-v` option prints all files being transferred. The `--numeric-ids` option may be relevant if you sync to a remote location rather than a local disk.

To answer your initial question, you are likely interested in the **`-x`** option (`--one-file-system`). This prevents `rsync` from descending in other mount points such as `/proc` and `/sys`. Note however, that it will also avoid copying `/home` if that is on a different mount point. In that case you need to run another `rsync` command for `/home/`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed! sorry for the long wait.